# Django: An alternative to using composite keys

Tags: python, django, composite-primary-key

I have the following 2 tables.

1. Discount: id, supplier_id, buyer_id, discount_rate (with supplier_id and buyer_id being unique_together)
2. Product: id, product_name, supplier_id, buyer_id, price

Just to explain why I have a buyer_id in my product table:
A product is offered to a specific buyer only. So at the time of loading the products into my Product table, I already know who the potential buyer will be.

Discounts are not product-specific but rather a supplier would offer a discount specific to the buyer.
The discount_rate can change therefore I cannot capture the rate in the product table.
So when the user/buyer views a product, I want to get the discount_rate offered by suppliers to that specific buyer and calculate the discounted price.

I previously did this in ASP.NET by making the buyer_id and supplier_id composite keys and using that as a foreign key.

Since composite keys are not available in Django, how can I get the discount which applies to the buyer/supplier relationship?

I can change the database design, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `Discount.objects.get(supplier_id=<some_id>, buyer_id=<some_id>)`? I don't know why you need a composite key for this? Just query for the correct row...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I also had that idea in my serializer. But if the user views 100 invoices you would have 100 queries to the db. I thought a relationship between the tables would allow better performance. Another option could be to add your code within a for loop in the view and then serialize the result. But I am not sure whether I can add the discount field to the query result since product model has no such field. In asp.net MVC I would have used a ViewModel

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Your question is 'how can I get the discount which applies to the buyer/supplier relationship'--how are you stuck doing that, and is that actually your question?

Comment: I'll post a new question, thanks